# Is it possible to check status or turn on/off HDCP on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, hdcp

Is it possible to programatically check status or turn on/off HDCP on Mac OSX? Is there any official Apple documentation on this? I have seen elsewhere someone commented that it is not possible to turn off HDCP in OSx. I am ok with that but I need some definite proof that it is true.

Answer (score 0):

I also know that you can't turn it off. Once I tried to hook the output of a Mac to my device where I have the full control. Then I specified in the EDID of my device that I accept no HDCP protected data. By this way, your source should switch off if the HDCP is not a must on its side. However, that didn't work and I get no output from Mac.